# Klocwork 9 vs Klocwork 12

Tags: c++, c, klocwork

For the same code base, when executing klocwork, for two different versions of KW, we are getting difference in results.

For e.g. for a particular file, KW 9 is throwing the following error :

*#6325: Infinite loop
"file Path"
Code: INFINITE_LOOP.LOCAL | Severity: Error (2) | State: Existing | Status: Analyze | Taxonomy: C and C++ | Owner: unowned*

However, for KW 12, there is no such error.

Both the KW are on different machines so I suspect this may be due difference in configuration, but the configuration file "problems_default.pconf.xml" is same in both the cases.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

i can help you here. Klocwork is keep on tuning/adding checkers to detect all possible vulnerabilities.
the Checker "INFINITE_LOOP.LOCAL" got tuned/modified on Klocwork v10.1 and v12.0 to get accurate issue rate. This might have caused the difference in results. Please revert back if you need more clarification.